# Версии php - в чем плюсы и минусы?

Tags: php, контроль-версий

Приветствую, разработчики!

Уже не один год пишу сайты на php, но до данного момента особо не задумывался над тем, какие версии использовать и нужно ли отслеживать его последние обновления. Т.е. главное, что код работает. Решил изменить данный подход. Поэтому хочу спросить:

1. Был ли у вас опыт перехода с одной
       версии php на другую, более новую?
2. Какую версию вы сейчас используете?
3. В чем преимущества вашей текущей
       рабочей версии перед прежней?
4. Насколько есть острая необходимость
       отслеживания последних версий?
5. Какие показатели скорости, использования
       озу при обновлениях php (сравнение)?

Comment: одно слово: phpbrew

Comment: И вот еще:

> Какие показатели скорости, использования озу при обновлениях php (сравнение)?

В последних версиях этому было уделено очень много внимания, а к седьмой версии планируют целиком пересобрать движок (phpng). Я не гонял тесты, но чем свежее стоит версия - тем лучше. Тем не менее все равно пишу 5.3-совместимый код, потому что уже натыкались на всякие старые centos, где была куча проектов, из-за чего обновление было крайне нежелательно.

Answer (score 2):

sarcasm Если Вы пишите сайты, то вам не стоит задумываться над этим вопросом. /sarcasm

1. Да, если вы занимаетесь автоматизацией бизнес-логики либо работаете над крупными проектами.
2. 5.4.16 FPM/FastCGI CentOS.
3. traits, short array syntax.
4. В гибкой Enterprise разработке, скажем так, выше средней.
5. В некоторых моментах оптимизация есть, но в основном это новый функционал из коробки. Производительность зависит от рук вашего администратора LAMP.

Answer (score 1):

А вы сами почитайте [историю изменений версий](https://php.net/manual/en/appendices.php) и подумайте, надо вам знать это или нет: новые возможности самого языка, новые функции, не рекомендуемые функции, обратная совместимость и т.д. В новой версии 5.6.х, к примеру, появился оператор возведения в степень ** и нормальная поддержка переменных аргументов функции. При миграции с одной версии на другую тоже поможет.